# How to create an array from the existing array on basis of key and value match

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array I want that data belong to same day will appear on one index like in the below array I have same the date in 1 and 2 index so the result array should be like my `ewault` array so that data belonging to the same date will show up on same index. How can I do this?

My Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pkMessageID] => 6
            [fkPostID] => 4
            [messageSenderID] => 2
            [messageRecieverID] => 19
            [messageBody] => Nice
            [messageStatus] => 1
            [DateOnly] => 2015-07-07
            [messageDateAdded] => 2015-07-07 16:20:58
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pkMessageID] => 5
            [fkPostID] => 4
            [messageSenderID] => 19
            [messageRecieverID] => 2
            [messageBody] => Hi I am good how r u
            [messageStatus] => 1
            [DateOnly] => 2015-07-06
            [messageDateAdded] => 2015-07-06 16:14:05
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pkMessageID] => 4
            [fkPostID] => 4
            [messageSenderID] => 2
            [messageRecieverID] => 19
            [messageBody] => Hello akhilesh how r u
            [messageStatus] => 1
            [DateOnly] => 2015-07-06
            [messageDateAdded] => 2015-07-06 16:12:22
        )

)
```

However, the result array should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pkMessageID] => 6
            [fkPostID] => 4
            [messageSenderID] => 2
            [messageRecieverID] => 19
            [messageBody] => Nice
            [messageStatus] => 1
            [DateOnly] => 2015-07-07
            [messageDateAdded] => 2015-07-07 16:20:58
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
 [0] => Array
        (
            [pkMessageID] => 5
            [fkPostID] => 4
            [messageSenderID] => 19
            [messageRecieverID] => 2
            [messageBody] => Hi I am good how r u
            [messageStatus] => 1
            [DateOnly] => 2015-07-06
            [messageDateAdded] => 2015-07-06 16:14:05
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pkMessageID] => 4
            [fkPostID] => 4
            [messageSenderID] => 2
            [messageRecieverID] => 19
            [messageBody] => Hello akhilesh how r u
            [messageStatus] => 1
            [DateOnly] => 2015-07-06
            [messageDateAdded] => 2015-07-06 16:12:22
        )
)

)
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried out ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to achieve. Are you saying you want to group level 2 of the array based upon messageDateAdded? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @mituw16 yes i want that data belong to same date added should come in one level like in my result array data added on 2015-07-07 came on one index and data added on 2015-07-6 will come on different index

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the following:

```
$out = array();

foreach($input as $data)
{
    if( ! is_array($out[$data['DateOnly']])){
        $out[$data['DateOnly']] = array();
    }
    $out[$data['DateOnly']][] = $data;
}
```

I haven't the code, but i hope you get the idea. Simply use the date as an index in your array. So the result will be along the lines of.

```
[2015-7-6] => Array ( [0] => Array( DateOnly => 2015-7-6, ..))
[2015-7-7] => Array ( [0] => Array( DateOnly => 2015-7-7, .. ), [1] => Array(DateOnly => 2015-7-7 , .. ))
```

Comment: this is the working code  $out = array();

foreach($arrMessage as $data)
{
   // echo '<pre>';print_r($data['DateOnly']);die;
    if(  is_array($data['DateOnly'])){
        $out[$data['DateOnly']] = array();
    }
    $out[$data['DateOnly']][] = $data;
}